# How do I (in ASP.NET) determine if the connection is a remote connection?

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to implement a bit of functionality that will behave much like the CustomError pages: if the connection is remote function A() will run; else function B() will run.

The only problem I'm having is that I'm not sure the best way to determine a "remote" connection. Does it matter if I'm running my code on a shared web host? Can I rely on just comparing "my" IP to the request's IP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's easy in ASP.NET - just check `HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal`. It will be true when the request was made from the local computer, and false for a remote computer.

Comment: +1 You're correct. In fact Microsoft mentions `IsLocal` for creating safe error messages, also mentions custom error pages: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994a1482(VS.80).aspx